# Javascript Autocomple with multi coulmn and categorized suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, yui

Is there any JavaScript autocomplete which can show categorized suggestions in a multicolumn design like the one here http://www.healthgrades.com/. If there is a jquery or YUI plugin that would be better.

Comment: why don't you copy the website files and go through the js file to know the plugin used in that link.

Comment: They have made their own custom code. So I think it would not be legal to copy and hack it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create your own autocomplete, because you know what data you want to show and how to show, you can use `table structure` or `ul-li structure`. One more thing is that your back end all things shown depends on your back end what queries you needed to extract data. Your main issues is only design, as I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MultiColumn [plugin](https://github.com/deaconsoftware/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete) you might use.

Comment: I cant see the link. Did you forgot to copy it?

Comment: There is a hyperlink 'plugin' in my answer. Ok. I am once again copying it here for you to SEE `https://github.com/deaconsoftware/jQueryUI.MulticolumnAutocomplete`

Comment: Thank you. But this plugin addresses different problem than mine. It cannot be modified to do what I need.

Comment: Are you sure it cannot be modified to do what you need?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Please see reference link I posted in my question.